# Expression using ternary operator

Tags: c, ternary-operator

```
a+=b>=300?b=100:a==100;
```

If `a` and `b` are initialized to `100` and `200` respectively,
what will be the values of `a` and `b` after executing the ternary operator?

The answer was `a=101`, `b=200`.

How is this possible?

Comment: Is this homework? Just curious.

Comment: It may be homework, but the question is not about the result, but a call for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Just add some parentheses and spaces to make it more readable and it should be obvious:

```
a += ((b >= 300) ? (b = 100) : (a == 100));
```

(Refer to a [C operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) to see why the parentheses can be placed where they are in the above expression.)

So this is essentially just:

```
a += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator has nothing to do with it, basically it just adds clutter here. Your program is equivalent to `a += a==100`. Which gives `a += 1`, since the result of == is a boolean 1=true.

Answer (score 1):

First add some spaces to make this statement expression easier to parse visually:

```
a += b >= 300 ? b = 100 : a == 100;
```

Then parse it according to the C grammar (which is subtly different from the java or javascript grammars in this particular case):

```
a +=
      (b >= 300) ?
           b = 100 :
           a == 100
      ;
```

Since `b = 200`, the test `b >= 300` evaluates to false and the first branch of the ternary operator is **not** evaluated, but the second branch is and `a == 100` evaluates to `1` as `a` is indeed equal to `100`. The result of the ternary operator, `1`, is added to `a`, hence the new value for `a` is `101`.  `b` is unchanged.